# Make my web app authorize with google oAuth

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am trying to login with Google oAuth. But when ever i try to login with oAuth it ask for permission. From the code i realize that there need to add the authorization . I have gone through web and found another way to make the app authorize which is complete different than what i have used here. Is there any way so that i can just modify or add a function so that i will be able to make my app authorize with google oAuth ? I am using php and javascript for my web app.

```
var loginFinished = function(authResult)
{
  if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) {
    var btnLogOut=document.getElementById("social-integration-logout");

    accessToken=authResult['access_token']; 
    expiresIn=authResult['expires_in'];
    console.log(authResult);    
     gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', function()
      {
        gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get()
          .execute(function(resp)
          {
          var id = resp.id;             
          });
      });

  } else {
    console.log('Sign-in state: ' + authResult['error']);
  }   
};




var options = {
  'callback': loginFinished,
  'approvalprompt': 'force',
  'clientid': '',
  'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
  'requestvisibleactions': 'http://schemas.google.com/CommentActivity http://schemas.google.com/ReviewActivity',
  'cookiepolicy': 'single_host_origin'
};

var renderBtn = function()
{
  gapi.signin.render('btn_google_login', options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you explain what issue you are having, i.e., what is not working? I notice that your script has 'approvalprompt': 'force', which will force the authorization dialog to always display. You may want to remove it so that returning users do not have to consent again. But I am not confident that this was your question.